# Access multiple values from dictionary vertically

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have to fetch values from a dictionary vertically.

```
mydict={'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4],'c':[0,9]}
keys=list(mydict.keys())
values=list(mydict.values())
```

Simple Output

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] #keys

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 9]] #values
```

Desired output:

```
def fetch_value(mydict):
   ... #do something
   return v1,v2

##output
v1=[1,3,0] 
v2=[2,4,9]
```

I don't want to use any for loop here as it took time and I have a very large dataset.Please suggest any faster way to do that.

Comment: Every solution to this will use a loop, either explicitly or under the hood. Just use a loop.

Comment: `list(zip(*d.values()))` this should do the trick. But no matter what way you choose to do it a loop will be involved

Comment: "I don't want to use any for loop here" you have to, implicitly or explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydict={'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4],'c':[0,9]}
print(list(zip(*mydict.values())))
```

output

```
[(1, 3, 0), (2, 4, 9)]
```

You can unpack the resulting list or access list elements as needed

Comment: Thankyou, this method is really very fast compared to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), as it is very efficient when managing big data sets:

```py
import pandas as pd

mydict={'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4],'c':[0,9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

# `values` will give you a numpy array
v1 = df.iloc[0].values
v2 = df.iloc[1].values
```

Comment: pandas is overkill in this case.

Comment: OP wants something efficient for big datasets. Pandas is the best suited for it

Comment: What OP said was they didn't want to use loops due to some irrational and misplaced fear that they are inherently inefficient on large data sets. So pandas might be applicable to their overall project, but for this specific problem, it's overkill as their question is based on a false premise.

Comment: Well, for loops are indeed less efficient than vectorized numpy operations. OP gave us a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show what he wants as a result. And he asks how to do this operation efficiently because it will be applied to big data sets. Finally, variaty of options could give to OP (and others interested) different possibilities to solve their problem, which is the one of the biggest positive sides of the Python

Comment: Also, if you are going to use pandas, better `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['v1', 'v2'], data = mydict.values())`. And your example has an error - v1 and v2 refer to same row.

Comment: Thanks for catching the error. About the actual DataFrame layout - I think it is more the question of the final task

Answer (score 0):

```
mydict={'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4],'c':[0,9]}

def fetch_values(dicto):
  n1 = []
  n2 = []
  for i in dicto:
    n1.append(dicto[i][0])
    n2.append(dicto[i][1])
  return (n1,n2)

fetch_values(mydict)
```

([1, 3, 0], [2, 4, 9])

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28251554)

Comment: @mightyWOZ how is this "link only"? The answer misses code description but this is not a reason to delete it. programandoconro please always describe your code - how and why it solves the issue. Quality of your post will significantly improve and your posts won't appear in low quality queue.

Comment: @Ruli Thank you for you advice, I will start doing it like that.